# ETL: Python to SQL pipeline duplicate checking options

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I got a question about checking duplicates using Python MYSQL Connector.
I have a fact table(sales) which consists of 2 million row of sales data since 2018.
Plus a bunch of dimension tables.

In my current python workflow, it:

1. Reads original data sources -> 2.Performs cleaning -> 3.Load into MySQL tables

SQL connector provides "append" and "replace" if exists. It works fine by using "replace" for all dimension tables as the tables are being replaced with the most updated data.

However, when it comes to fact tables, if using "replace", it will get rid of the entire table and replace with only the inserted data. If using "append", it will not check for duplicates before appending.

And I am currently loading entire cleaned pandas df using:

> sales.to_sql(name='sales', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')

I've came up with 2-3 potential options to deal with this, but not sure if they are proper:

- Option1: SELECT InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber from SQL => Assign to a pandas df called "existing_records" => drop rows from new pandas df "sales" if isin SQL => Insert the rest.
- Option2: Create a local CSV check file which represents the newest sales data for 1 week or 1 month, everytime when loading the daily sales into MySQL, use this csv file to check for duplicate instead before loading, should perform faster.

Since in the end I will need to automate this ETL process, and I might need to make sure its robust and scalable. Much appreciated if anyone could check my solutions for me or suggest better options if any. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a staging table.

1. **Load Data into a Staging Table**: First, load your new data into a temporary staging table in MySQL.
2. **Run Duplicate Checks**: identify and remove duplicates from the staging table based on the existing records in the `sales` table.
3. **Insert de-deduplicated0 records into the main Table**: Insert the records from the staging table into the main sales table.